# iOS no audio after hold using webrtc and Call Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, voip, callkit

I am facing some serious issue with my internet calling app. We have discovered this in final testing, we are ready for launch but now this webrtc issue is some thing where we stuck. 
I am sharing the reference link of same issue as well. From this reference link i came to know that you are the call kit expert.
Here is the link : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=8126#

This is the issue:
**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

1. Create an WebRTC application with callkit integration
2. Hold a call
3. Unhold a call

**What is the expected result?**

You will still be able to hear the other side, and the other side will be able to hear you.

**What do you see instead?**

No audio being heard on either side.

**Test Case: My internet call is set on hold /unhold when i receive other call from a landline.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edit the WebRtc framework, a patch work for me. You can follow this link for more information: 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=8126#

You can download framework with this patch here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=114WjEF5bP1XwSN_AbY5ctkgJZKjlfduB

Comment: Hello can you please refer this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023429/how-can-we-handle-multiple-calls-with-pjsip-and-callkit